# Caps Lock implicitly on

Tags: php, capslock

I am creating a form in PHP. I want that all the form should be filled in capital letters. No matter if the user's caps lock is on or off, it should get implicitly on. And data in the databse shold also be saved in capitals. But just for the email field caps lock should be off. That is no matter whether user's caps lock is on or off, email should be filled in running case. Is there any way to do so. Please reply

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do this is another matter?

But in PHP

```
   $str = "A string IN mixed CAse"
   $str = strtoupper ($str);
   echo $str;
```

See [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

Comment: This is I know, What I want is that it should not allow any small letter on the form.

Comment: You want to use Javascript as well

Comment: Yes. Actually I am using a suggestion box, that shows the already added instiutions. In that suggestion box, for example, if I type 'a', then it gives me a suggestion like 'aNNA UNIVERSITY' whereas the actual data was 'ANNA UNIVERSITY'. I don't know how to resolve this problem; thus I thought if I could make caps lock on implicitly, just to fix that issue.

Comment: If you know how to fix that, that will be more helpful.

Comment: Post another question with the Javascript in it